# How can I iterate over a list of a user's followers and each of the follower's followers in a template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I am asking this question again because I did not receive a satisfactory answer in my previous attempt. It may be difficult for me to fully convey the issue I am trying to resolve, but I will do my best to provide a clear and concise explanation.

[image].

I am trying to run a query that retrieves a list of followers, as well as the list of followers and followings for each follower. I have included an image that illustrates this structure. I am currently using the following code to attempt this, but it is not producing the expected results. Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong and how I can correctly run this query?

```
views.py  
   def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(FollowerView,self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        user = context['user']
        user_com = User.objects.get(username=user)
        myfollowers = user_com.is_following.all()
        
        followers_Array =[]
        followerings_Array =[]
        
        for target_list in myfollowers:
            user_obj = User.objects.get(username=target_list)

            followers_obj = user_obj.is_following.all()
            print(followers_obj,'name o  ki line')
            followerings_Array.append(followerings_Array)
            print(followers_obj,user_obj)

            followerings_obj = user_obj.userprofile.follower.all()
            followerings_Array.append(followerings_obj)
            print(followerings_obj,user_obj)
        print(followerings_Array,'arry one one one ')
        context['myfollowers_data']= followers_Array
        context['myfollowerings_data']= followerings_Array
         
        return context
```

I am currently using two arrays in my code, but I would prefer to avoid doing so if possible. My current implementation is not producing the desired output when I return the arrays in the context. Can you suggest an alternative approach that allows me to display the data in the manner illustrated in the image, and can you review the followers template to see if I am making any mistakes there?

```
{% for follower in user.is_following.all %}
                <div class="followers-body">
                 <img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="{{follower.avatar.url}}" alt="">
                 <div class="name-box">
                 
                  <h4>{{follower}}</h4>
                  <span>@{{follower}}</span>
                  <div class="followers-base">
                   <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item full-width">
                     <div class="pull-left" style="margin-right: 20px;">
                     {% if myfollowers_data %}
                     {% for user in myfollowers_data %}
                      <img src="{{user.userprofile.avatar.url}}" alt="" class="img-circle max-w-40 ">
                      {% endfor %}
                      {% endif %}
                      <span> {{myfollowers_data.count}} Followers </span>
                     </div><!--/ pull-left -->
                    </li> 
                    <li class="list-group-item full-width">
                     <div class="pull-left">
                       {% for usr in myfollowerings_data %}
                      <img src="{{usr.userprofile.avatar.url}}" alt="" class="img-circle max-w-40 ">
                      {% endfor %}
                      <span> {{myfollowerings_data|length}}  Following </span>
                     </div><!--/ pull-right -->
                    </li><!--/ list-group-item -->                     
                   </ul>
                  </div><!--/ followers-base -->
                 </div><!--/ name-box -->
                 <span><a href="#" class="kafe-btn kafe-btn-mint-small"> Follow</a></span>
                </div><!--/ followers-body -->
                {% endfor %}

models.py
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follower = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name ='is_following',blank=True,)
    close_friends = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='my_close_friends', blank=True)
    rank = models.ManyToManyField(Rank, related_name='rank', default='Newbie', blank=True)

    avatar = models.ImageField(("Avatar"), upload_to='displays', default = '1.jpg',height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None,blank = True)
    create_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
        
    @property
    def email_address(self):
        return self.user.email

   
    objects = ProfileManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("profiles:final_detail", kwargs={"username": self.user.username})
```

If more code in require than tell me in a comment session. I will update my question with that information.

Comment: Can you share your model structure?

Comment: Check my question , I just updated my question and addedd the model

Comment: So you want to traverse a list of a user's followers, and each of the follower's followers in the template? is that it?

Comment: Yeah just like i show in picture

Comment: each follower's followers and followings as well

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this should all be achievable from the template:

template.html:

```
<!-- users followers -->
{% for follower1 in user.is_following.all %}
  <img src="{{ follower1.avatar.url }}"/>

  <!-- followers followers -->
  {% for follower2 in follower1.is_following.all %}
    <img src="{{ follower2.avatar.url }}"/>
    ...

  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `follower.my_followers.all` is returning nothing on template.

Comment: Well I was just repeating your code - but it looks like you called that field simply `follower`, so `follower.follower.all` should work - see my edits.

Comment: Is nothing showing up at all - or is just the second loop not working?

Comment: Just nothing printing anything

Comment: I had a type in there - I fixed it now - want to check again?

Comment: Yeah it printed now but instead of followers , it is printing followings

Comment: i want followers

Comment: Okay, if you want to reverse the direction it looks like you can just replace `follower` with `is_following` - see edits.

Comment: I did this but now getting nothing